# How to import matplotlib in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, anaconda

I'm trying to import matplotlib to python 3.7, but I keep getting

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'
```

despite the fact that I downloaded it in my Anaconda Prompt (Anaconda3) using

```
python -m pip install -U pip
python -m pip install -U matplotlib
```

What am I doing wrong here? And how get I get matplotlib

Comment: If the installation was successful, you're importing it in an environment which is not the one where you installed it.

Comment: Im using IDLE python 3.7. How do I install matplotlib to that?

Comment: In that case install it outside of anaconda.

Comment: That's what I dont get. I tried pip install matplotlib in cmd but it doesnt recognize pip

Comment: Then you need to first install pip itself.

Comment: My cmd prompt doesn't even recognize python. I dont understand I have python 3.7 and am using an Idle. I HAVE PYTHON

Comment: have you installed using anaconda or only u are installing with python

Comment: I installed using anaconda. That must be why. From the Anaconda Command Prompt, how do I open the python shell?

Comment: Since you're already using Anaconda why not use Conda, too? Combined with Anaconda Navigator, this sort of messing around isn't necessary.

Comment: Anaconda already includes `matplotlib` and `pip`. You likely messed up your **base** env by reinstalling them from PyPI. Try starting over and resist using `pip` in Conda.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Python 3.7, so the Python packages need to be compatible with Python 3.x, not Python 2.x. Run the following commands.

```
python3 -m pip install -U pip
```

Print the pip3 version to verify the installation:

```
pip3 --version
```

Install matplotlib:

```
pip3 install -U matplotlib
```

Answer (score -1):

first install pip via [get-pip](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py).

Then install matplotlib by this command `pip install matplotlib`

NOTE:type all these commands first in powershell or cmd and then try it on your IDE's console.

NOTE2: In case you don't know how to download get-pip, simply right-click and click on save as.... button once after you clicked on the link included above, and then save it in your Desktop, Then go to powershell using `cd C:/Users/(You'r username)/Desktop` and then run `python get-pip.py` command, when you made sure that pip is fully installed in powershell or cmd, then you can install it in your IDE's console for once and then run `pip install matplotlib` or `python -m pip install -U pip
python -m pip install -U matplotlib` as you suggested.

NOTE3:I Guess if all what I said above possibly may not work, you must uninstall python and reinstall it again, But with one difference, YOU MUST enable python add to path at the beginning of installation so that all what I said above works for you flawlessly